# Repeater loses it's data after UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

After I choose the data from the DropDownList, I save it's ID inside a ViewState but in a second control page this data (ProjectID) returns 0 instead of the saved ID.
The rowRepeater is inside an UpdatePanel but if I reload the page the ID is passed correctly. Could anyone help me?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="m_RowRepeater" runat="server">
   
 <%--Riferimento alla riga contenente i giorni del mese--%>
    <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <%--Header row has special "ProjectID"  --%>
                    <cdgWebCtrl:FerieRichiestaMonthRow ID="FerieRichiestaMonthRowHeader" runat="server" ProjectID="-1" ProjectTitle="Commessa (ID)" ProjectLeader="Capo Progetto" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
  <%--Fa riferimento ad un progetto--%>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <cdgWebCtrl:FerieRichiestaMonthRow runat="server" 
                        ProjectID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idPrj") %>'
                        ProjectTitle='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserLabelTitle") %>'
                        ProjectLeader='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CapoPrj") %>'
                       />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
   
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["project_id"] = this.ProjectID;
    ApplyRowModeValue();
}
else if (ProjectID == 0 && ViewState["project_id"] != null)
{
    this.ProjectID = (int)ViewState["project_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that view state is ONLY for the current web page. If you jump or navigate to a different page? Then view state is lost.

If you need to persist value(s) when moving or navigating to a different page?

Then I suggest using session() to pass that information to the next page in question.

However, if such values are not persisting correctly on the current page? Then in most cases, it often the page load event is the issue.
Page load event fires each and every time a post-back occurs, even for a simple button click. And that page load event fires before say the button click event code stub.

So, often what occurs is we have some simple setup code in the page load event. (To setup controls or load data into a grid view, or repeater as per this example). Thus, on each post-back, if that code runs to re-load the repeater, then values can be lost since the repeater is "again" being re-loaded.

Thus, in most cases, the page load event will require a "all important" code stub inside of a test for If not IsPostBack (Postback = false).

e.g., this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCityCbo();
    }

    void LoadCityCbo()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = 
            new SqlCommand("Select City FROM City ORDER BY City");
        General.Cbo(cboCity, cmd, "", "City", "Select City");
    }
```

So, in above we on page load are filling out a combo box. However, since we wrapped the code inside of an if (!IsPostBack), then that code will ONLY run on first page load - not each additional button click and post back.

At the end of the day?

Viewstate is "per page", and is lost if you navigate to another page. So, using session() would be a better choice, since session() is "per user" and that information travels from web page to web page, and “persists” from page to page.

So, view state can’t be used to pass values to another web page, but session() can be.